# WMI failed to parse WDG method

Tags: grub2, system-installation, bios, reboot, sgx

I use a Dell Inspiron 3501 and I was able to install Ubuntu 21.04 successfully. I did

```
sudo apt update 
apt upgrade
```

and restarted the OS. But I am getting this error

> wmi failed to parse wdg method.

Kindly help.

Comment: I experienced same thing. I'm looking for some log files and maybe "undo" upgrade. I checked question "https://serverfault.com/questions/277479/debian-how-do-i-check-the-last-time-package-upgrades-updates-were-run". I'm in a `Dell Inspiron 15` in an `Elementary OS 6 - Linux 5.11.0-34-generic - based on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

Comment: Hey @Jefferson Jerome, Did you solve this error? I'm struggling with the same message. Thanks in advance.